# mysql table joins: multiple join to same table but with different parameters

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query against my mysql database.

```
SELECT
  mn.id,
  mn.created_date,
  mn.created_by,
  mnt.description,
  u.handle,
  mn.admin_request_company_id
FROM member_notification mn,
  member_notification_type mnt,
  member m,
  user u
WHERE mn.member_notification_type_id = mnt.id
    AND mnt.name = 'COMPANYVALIDATION'
    AND mn.created_by = m.id
    AND m.user_id = u.id;
```

This is working fine however I now need to extend this to go get a company name off another table. The problem is that to do that I need to re-join against the member table using the key 
mn.admin_request_company_id, however I'm not sure how to go about this.

I've tried creating a member m2 table but I'm getting errors. What I'm trying to achieve is something along the lines of the following pseudo code:

```
SELECT
  mn.id,
  mn.created_date,
  mn.created_by,
  mnt.description,
  u.handle,
  mn.admin_request_company_id,
  /*c.company_name*/
FROM member_notification mn,
  member_notification_type mnt,
  member m,
  /*member m2,*/
  /*company c,*/
  /*user u*/
WHERE mn.member_notification_type_id = mnt.id
    AND mnt.name = 'COMPANYVALIDATION'
    AND mn.created_by = m.id
    AND m.user_id = u.id
   /* AND mn.admin_request_company_id = m2.company_id
    AND m2.company_id = c.id*/
```

**edit**
Table structures as are follows:

```
CREATE TABLE member_notification (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
item_id INT NULL,
member_id INT NULL,
text VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
member_notification_type_id INT NULL,
marked_read VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
created_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
created_by VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
admin_request_company_id INT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=innodb;

CREATE TABLE member_notification_type (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
description VARCHAR(50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=innodb;

CREATE TABLE member (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
user_id INT NULL,
company_id INT NULL,
soft_delete VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT 'N',
member_status_id INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=innodb;


CREATE TABLE user (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
handle VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
date_of_birth VARCHAR(50) NULL,
soft_delete VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT 'N',
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=innodb;

CREATE TABLE company (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
owning_company_id INT NULL,
company_type_id INT NULL,
name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
company_details_id INT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=innodb;
```

Comment: what are your tables structures

Comment: hmm the bold doesn't appear to work but the added sections are between the ** comments

Comment: Could you provide the error you get?

Comment: can you provide same data and expected output

Comment: @Bluefeet have a good solution, you can make tests [HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59b52/10) using his answer inserting data before the selection in the right side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you just want to use the following which just adds a second join to the `member` table:

```
SELECT
  mn.id,
  mn.created_date,
  mn.created_by,
  mnt.description,
  u.handle,
  mn.admin_request_company_id,
  c.name
FROM member_notification mn
INNER JOIN member_notification_type mnt
  on mn.member_notification_type_id = mnt.id
INNER JOIN member m1
  on mn.created_by = m1.id
INNER JOIN user u
  on m1.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN member m2
  on mn.admin_request_company_id = m2.company_id
INNER JOIN company c
  on m2.company_id = c.id
WHERE mnt.name = 'COMPANYVALIDATION'
```

Notice, I changed your current joins in the `WHERE` clause to ANSI join syntax. I also used an `INNER JOIN` between the tables, you might need to use a `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

To join twice on a table, select the table twice using a different name:

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM 
  member m1,
  member m2,
  someCouplingTable t
WHERE
  m1.Id = t.leftId
  AND m2.Id = t.rightId
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it

```
SELECT
  mn.id,
  mn.created_date,
  mn.created_by,
  mnt.description,
  u.handle,
  mn.admin_request_company_id
FROM member_notification mn
  left join member_notification_type mnt
    on mnt.id = mn.member_notification_type_id
  left join member m
    on m.id = mn.created_by
  left join user u
    on u.id = m.user_id
  left join company as c
    on c.id = m.company_id
where mnt.name = 'COMPANYVALIDATION'
```